# Python in ArcGIS

Tags: python, arcgis

I wrote the following code, which results in an error and I don't know how to fix it to work.

The code is:

```
# Name: ClipGDBtoNewGDB.py
# Description: Take an input GDB, create a list, iterate through each 
feature class, clipping it and writing it to a new GDB.
# Author: tuilbox
# Import system modules
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
# Set workspace
env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
# Set local variables
fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
clip_features = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
output_directory=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
xy_tolerance = ""
outgdb=os.path.join(output_directory, arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3))
if not arcpy.Exists(outgdb):
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(output_directory, 
arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3))
# Execute Clip within for loop
for fc in fclist:
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc, clip_features, os.path.join(outgdb, fc))
```

The error is: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/GIS_Joseph/Lab10_Joseph/ClipGDBtoNewGDB.py", line 17, in <module>
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(output_directory, arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 18878, in CreateFileGDB
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000735: File GDB Location: Value is required
ERROR 000735: File GDB Name: Value is required
Failed to execute (CreateFileGDB).`

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With this type of question it would be helpful to let us know what parameters you are passing into your script.  Have you passed a valid parameter in position 3? Use arcpy.AddMessage to double check what value you are attempting to pass to arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management.